# What is the meaning of totalSlotMs for a BigQuery job?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the meaning of the statistics.query.totalSlotMs value returned for a completed BigQuery job? Except for giving an indication of relative cost of one job vs the other, it's not clear how else one should interpret the number. For example, how does the slot-milliseconds number relate to the stack driver reported total slot usage for a given project (which needs to stay below 2000 for on demand BigQuery usage)?

The docs are a bit terse ('[Output-only] Slot-milliseconds for the job.')

Comment: The sum of time for all the slots used within that query in terms of milliseconds. Although this metric may sound counter intuitive at first, I think it can be useful in conjunction of taking into account the start and end time of said query, as well for the fact 2000 slots represents 2000 milliseconds available per millisecond.

Comment: @softdevlife I ran a query which resulted in the below stats. 
Elapsed time: 12.1 sec
Slot time consumed:  14 hr 12 min
total_slot_ms: 51147110 ( which is 14 hr 12 min) 

We are on an on-demand pricing plan. So the max slots would be 2000. 
That being said, if I used 2000 slots for the whole 12.1 seconds span then I should end up with total_slot_ms as 24200000 ( which is 2000*12.1*1000). However, the total_slot_ms is  51147110. Average number of slots used are 51147110/121000 = 4225 ( which is way above 200). Can you explain how I ended up used more 2000 slots?

Comment: BigQuery on-demand does support limited bursting.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#December_10_2019

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to have a 'slots' metric in the same units at which slots of reservation are sold to customers.

For example, imagine that you have a 20-second query that is continuously consuming 4 slots. In that case, your query is using 80,000 totalSlotMs (4 * 20,000).

This way you can determine the average number of slots even if the peak number of slots differs as, in practice, the number of workers will fluctuate over the runtime of a query.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable way to interpret it and also allows us to calculate the average slot usage of a query.